# LaTeX lstlisting's style for character literals

Tags: lstlisting

As we all know, we can specify the style for `string` literals in `lstlisting` by using `stringstyle=` But in some parts of my code, I have `character` literals (i.e. when I `.Split()` some string). And those are not interpreted as strings (that's actually good). So I want to color them. Let's say strings are green, so I want to color those character literals in red/orange (kinda like in Visual Studio).

So my question here is: Is there a way to color those character literals in lstlisting, so i.e. this line:

```
var foo = bar.Split(')');
```

would get its `')'` part in color?

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with C language, therefore the code below might do the work

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines = true, frame = trBL, tabsize = 4, basicstyle = \small \ttfamily, keywordstyle = \color{blue}, stringstyle = \color{red}, rulecolor = \color{black}}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = C]
var foo = bar.Split(')');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

which would produce

> [image: string]

Comment: This would color all strings. I think the OP wants to distinguish between `'<char>'` and `“<string>“`.

Comment: `var foo` is not valid C unless `var` is a typedef.  It's probably JavaScript or so.

Comment: @HenriMenke I am not quite familiar with `C`, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

`listings` only supports a single `stringstyle` value, even if different string types have been defined. If you want to define a new string type with a different style, you can use the optional argument of the `morestring` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    string = [d]{"},
    stringstyle = {\color{blue}},
    morestring = [d][\color{orange}]{'}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
var bar = "foo(bar)baz";
var foo = bar.Split(')');
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]

`[d]` here defines a string where the opening and closing delimiter is the same (`'`), and `[\color{orange}]` is the style to be applied to the new string type.

Comment: Adding `basicstyle=\ttfamily` is probably a good idea.